# how to give margins between two text view as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout

My designer has given me the layout spec. as shown in image, so i have to give a exact 20dp gap between first `TextView`(Verification Code Resent) and second `TextView`(Please check your text message...) but their is always a default padding for `TextView` that increase the gap between these two `TextViews`, i want to know is it possible to give exact 20dp margin between these textview ,if not does my desiner need to make some changes in layout spec, i'm confused please help me..[image]

Comment: Can you share your layout and the screenshot of the layout you obtained?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:includeFontPadding="false"` in your XML for the TextViews.
As an alternative, you can set `setIncludeFontPadding (false)` on the TextView in your Java code.

Comment: i had tried  this but this is not removing the padding,..NOTE- i,m using custom font also .

Comment: If you are using a custom font, chances are the font itself has the extra padding and not the text view. You can either edit the font and remove this padding of find another font that has no padding on the top and bottom of the letter.

Comment: if my custom font have this default padding, then is there any way to deal with it.

Comment: Check out a font editor to edit the font. This site may help: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-create-your-own-fonts-and-edit-truetype-fonts/